# Character array seems to grow after memcpy(), what is the problem?

Tags: c

I'm using a char[] of size 4 but when I use memcpy() function it stores 8 characters in it and also the character array length becomes 8. What is happing?

I don't want to use malloc ok.

```
char strRoh[4]={'\0'};
```

and then

```
memcpy(strRoh,Dump+22,4);
```

Now tell me whats wrong with this

```
char strIP[]="hhhhhhhh";
char strRoh[4]={'\0'};
char strTheta[4]={'\0'};
char strTimeStamp[6]={'\0'};
char strNMDump[48]={'\0'};
```

is there any problem with decelerations cause when i change there order they strings also change there size now strroh is getting 10 chars

what a hell is going on with this

Comment: show your code. don't be shy.

Comment: Can you show the code in question?

Comment: Make sure you copy the size of the array and not the size of the pointer.

Comment: How are you determining the length? Do you use `strlen()`?  Maybe your source doesn't end with `0` at the end, so you're seeing the wrong length.  Show us a minimal, complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: We really need to see your code to be able to help you.

Comment: *"i don't want to use malloc ok."* Okay, but I strongly recommend you use a different language then. Trying to use C without using `malloc` and `free` is...well, challenging. Switch to C++ (although there are similar issues there), C#, Java, Python, JavaScript...

Comment: What, exactly  is leading you to believe that strRoh is 8 bytes long after memcpy()?

Comment: If you do `printf("%s\n", Dump+22);`, do you get more than 3 characters?  If you want to copy 4 characters and still be able to treat `strRoh` as a string, you need `strRoh` to be of size 5 (one for the final 0). `char strRoh[5] = { 0 };` (followed by copying 4 bytes).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Its perfectly acceptable to use C without dynamic memory allocation. In fact, on some platforms (especially space hardened ones), dynamic memory allocation is forbidden. I would agree that refusing to use malloc() and free() simply because it seems 'too hard' is silly, but avoiding them as an engineering choice is sometimes sensible.

Comment: i have checked by applying break points and check its value statement by statement and it got a string length of 8 and some times 10 but it shows only 4 characters are stored in string.

Comment: @moon: you need length 5 array to be able to store a string of length 4 in C.  C strings always have `0` at the end, which is not included in the length of the string.  `char hello[5] = "hello";` is not a string, `char hello[6] = "hello";` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C strings are 0-terminated.  This means that if you want to have a string of length `n` in C, you need `n+1` `char`s for it:

```
char hello[5] = "hello";
```

is not a string, because `hello` has space for 5 `char`s, and it doesn't end with `0`.

```
char hello[6] = "hello";
```

is a string, and has 6 characters: `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, `0`.

To be able to use string related functions in C, you need the terminating 0.

So, change your code to have:

```
char strRoh[5]={'\0'};
char strTheta[5]={'\0'};
char strTimeStamp[7]={'\0'};
char strNMDump[49]={'\0'};
```

Note that in C, when you do:

```
char hello[] = "hello";
```

the compiler does the counting for you, and makes `hello` an array of size 6 (one terminating 0):

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof hello);
```

will print 6.

Comment: ok thanx i have done it before you ans but you got the point now i take the size 5 instead of 4 but string length is still 4 and it works for me any how problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying type of the objects pointed by both the source and destination pointers are irrelevant for `memcpy`; The result is a binary copy of the data.

The function does not check for any terminating null character in source - it always copies exactly num bytes. My guess is you are not adding a terminating null and trying to access it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have any kind of boundary check on its data types.

So what you are probably "seeing" when debugging the code is that it shows you 8 bytes in the array. As someone else says, you might be trying to view it as a string and do not have a terminating zero byte. This is quite normal in C, and it is one of the aspects of the language that makes it very hard to understand.

I can recommend you read a good introduction to memory and pointer handling under C, or switch to a managed language like C#, VB.NET, Java, Perl, Python etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that if char has 2 bytes if you memcpy to a byte array you might be getting 8 bytes, that is 2 bytes for each char.

I am however rusty at this C/C++ things. So hopefully somebody with more experience will give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have a char array of 4 bytes and you writing full 4 bytes during memcpy without leaving any space for the terminating null character. Declare your array as 5 bytes and initialize it all to null (which you are already doing) and everything should be fine.